# How to detect an external program monitoring your process?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible in .net to determine if another program is monitoring your process?

What I mean here is I have an exe running and if someone launches procmon.exe or some other app that tries to read some information about my exe, I want my exe to log this.

Comment: This may be better suited for security.stackexchange.com depending on why you want to know if someone is watching you (your program).

Comment: If there were a way to do this, the attacker would just patch your program so the API always returned "nope".

Comment: I just downloaded an app and I wanted to know where the files were being written to (when it was streaming). What happened was my trial license disappeared/expired. I thought that was kind of cool and wanted to know how it was done from a technical stand point.

Comment: @JD.: Most likely with a blacklist of known debuggers/inspectors, and it probably triggers if they are running, regardless of which program they are actually being used on.  The topic you are asking about is known as [*anti-debugging*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Anti-debugging), there's a ton of information around, most of it involves some pretty gnarly techniques.

Comment: @BenVoigt : All these years coding and that is the first I have heard about it (what shame) :). Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vast and complex topic, and I'm only acquainted with its existence, not an expert.  So all I can offer is a search term:

- *anti-debugging*

It covers detection of monitoring tools, countermeasures to prevent inspection, and obfuscation to make information gained through monitoring quite useless.

Do be aware that there is an arms race between the reversers, who want to debug any and all code running on their system, and the DRM designers<sup>1</sup>, who want to protect their secrets from curious minds.  Unless you're willing to dedicate your life to becoming an expert, you're probably stuck buying solutions from someone who is.  Or just deciding that it isn't worth it.

<sup>1</sup> Even if you believe content owners have the moral right<sup>2</sup> to ban reverse engineering, please note that no one benefits from protective obscurity quite as much as malware authors.

<sup>2</sup> Also, it's quite different to maintain a neutral expression.  But I tried.

Answer (score 1):

The monitoring process can either **take information about your process directly from the Operating System** (e.g. TaskManager, perfmon, etc.). In this case your process does not know anything about it.

In another case, the monitoring process could **attach and debug** your process. When the debugger attaches to your process the latter stops and the debugger can get information about its execution. So your process cannot "**detach the debugger on its own**" without some additional security measures.

Comment: One of the simplest things that can be done is to install a benign debugger, which will block any other invasive debugger from attaching.  But there's always non-invasive (passive) debugging.